# Filter Repeated Messages In Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

**PREFACE:**

In our organization we're trying to use Kafka to solve a problem that involves capturing changes in an Oracle Database and send through Kafka. It's in fact a CDC, we are using Kafka Connector for that.

We catch the changes in Oracle, using Oracle Flashback queries, this allows us to get the timestamp of the change and operation (Insert, Delete, Update) involved.

Once some change is made in a table we observe, the Kafka Connector publishes this to a topic, we further read this topic using Kafka Streams.

The problem is that sometimes there are equal lines that appears in the Flashback query, because of some Update in the table that didn't change nothing (this triggers a flashback change too), or if the table has 100 columns, and we watch only 20, it end up that we see repeated lines in the query because none of those 20 fields has changed.

We use flashback to get changed rows (including excluded ones). In the connector we set timestamp+increment mode (timestamp is obtained by the field **versions_starttime** of flashback query)

Important: we can't touch the DB more than this, I mean, we can't create triggers instead of using this already Flashback scheme.

**THE QUESTION**

We're trying to filter records in Kafka, if some (key, value) is equally in content we want to discard. Note that, this is not exactly once semantics. The record will be repeated with large timestamps differences.

**If I use a KTable to check the last value of some record, how efficient this will be after a long period?**

I mean, internal state storage of consumers, is handled by RocksDB and a backed Kafka Topic, since if I use a non windowed KTable this internal space could end up being very large.

Which is considered a good approach in this scenario? To not overload Kafka Consumers internal state storage, and the same time being capable to know if the actual record was already processed time ago.

Comment: Which connector are you using? Have you evaluated other CDC options (e.g GoldenGate, Debezium, JDBC connector) ? ref: https://rmoff.net/2018/12/12/streaming-data-from-oracle-into-kafka-december-2018/

Comment: @RobinMoffatt We're using Standard Confluent's JDBC Connector. We know about GoldenGate, but can't afford right now

Comment: So you're using the JDBC connector, but with Flashback?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt yes that's it. We use flashback to get changed rows (including excluded ones). In the connector we set timestamp+increment mode (timestamp is obtained by the field versions_starttime of flashback query)

Comment: @JohnnyWiller, I think the internal state storage will be _only_ `O(numberOfPartitionHandleByConsumer * (numberOfUniqueKeys/numberOfPartitions))`. Is it to much for you?

Comment: @wardziniak It's an average of 3k rows every day. Since it'll growing indefinitely, I prefer to be careful about this. I'm thinking about checking an external KV store.